# How can I resolve this issue with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, flutter-dependencies

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

[image]

I'm a beginner with Flutter.

Here is the code that I've written:

```
   File?croppedImage=await ImageCropper().cropImage(
        sourcePath:filePath,maxHeight:1080,maxWidth:1080
    );
```

And I'm facing this error:

```
croppedFile can't be assigned to a variable of type file?
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of cropImage is CroppedFile

```
CroppedFile? croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(sourcePath:filePath,maxHeight:1080,maxWidth:1080 );
```